# Linkedin not picking up preview image from personal website

Tags: html, linkedin-api

I have a personal website that I refer to from Linkedin. I like the preview windows on my Linkedin profile to show a snapshot image of my website. However, I cannot seem to get this to work.

According to the [documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en) it must fulfill the following:

> ```
> Below are the og: tags that must exist and their correct format:
>
> <meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>
> <meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>
> <meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>
> <meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />
> Here are the image requirements specific to the LinkedIn sharing module:
>
> Max file size: 5 MB
> Minimum image dimensions: 1200 (w) x 627 (h) pixels
> Recommended ratio: 1.91:1
> ```

I have done exactly this and then run it through the linkedin inspection tool that is supposed to detect these as well as clearing the linkedin cache: https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/

It does pick up all my og tags in my header section of my index.html, except for the image og tag. It says it cannot find it at all. In my case, I'm linking to an image I have to github, like this:

```
  <meta name="image" property="og:image" content="https://github.com/XXX/XXX.github.io/blob/master/img/XXX.png">
```

(Size is 1641x851)

What else can I do to try and make this work? I have tried and made sure to verify all other suggested solutions